# yii2- saving datas to multiple rows from one form

Tags: yii2

I am so new to the yii2 framework, I have a form that I want to save each party score to correspond to each party abbreviation. I don't know how to go about it. here is my code.

the model -

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "announced_pu_results".
 *
 * @property int $result_id
 * @property string $polling_unit_uniqueid
 * @property string $party_abbreviation
 * @property int $party_score
 * @property string $entered_by_user
 * @property string $date_entered
 * @property string $user_ip_address
 */
class AnnouncedPuResults extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'announced_pu_results';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['polling_unit_uniqueid', 'party_abbreviation', 'party_score', 'entered_by_user', 'date_entered', 'user_ip_address'], 'required'],
        [['party_score'], 'integer'],
        [['date_entered'], 'safe'],
        [['polling_unit_uniqueid', 'entered_by_user', 'user_ip_address'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
       // [['party_abbreviation'], 'string', 'max' => 4],
    ];
}

  public function getPollingUnit()
  {

    return $this->hasOne(PollingUnit::className(), ['id' => 'polling_unit_uniqueid']);
  }
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'result_id' => 'Result ID',
        'polling_unit_uniqueid' => 'Polling Unit Uniqueid',
        'party_abbreviation' => 'Party Abbreviation',
        'party_score' => 'Party Score',
        'entered_by_user' => 'Entered By User',
        'date_entered' => 'Date Entered',
        'user_ip_address' => 'User Ip Address',
    ];
}
```

}

the controller  action is create ---

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new AnnouncedPuResults();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ){
        //&& $model->save()) {
        $post = yii::$app->request->post('AnnouncedPuResults');
        $party_score = $post['party_score'];
        $count = count($party_score);
         for($i =0 ; $i < $count; $i++) {
             $model->party_abbreviation = $post['party_abbreviation'];
             $model->polling_unit_uniqueid = $post['polling_unit_uniqueid'];
             $model->entered_by_user = $post['entered_by_user'];
             $model->date_entered = $post['date_entered'];
             $model->party_score = $post['party_score'];
             $model->save();
         }

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->result_id]);
    }else{

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

   }
}
```

this is the partial view form for the action create----

the screenshot of my form is attached
[image: i have a select box against an input box]

I want to save the results from my select boxes and the inputs the number of times they are selected to multiple rows in the database at a time
this is how the database looks like 
[image]
please help me out, I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: this isn't the correct way of doing this you should use formModel for the frontend and add validation to that form model and then load the attributes one by one in the loop to the `AnnouncedPuResults` model, as you need to have the  `$model = new AnnouncedPuResults();` statement inside the `foreach` so that a new instance is created every time, then loaded with values and saved, and you should use `transaction` block to perform this task. search a bit on google and start by creating a form model for this frontend form and then come back if you have questions

Comment: yes i actually use the form model, what i was trying to do was to save each selected party with its score with the date,uniqueid the  number of times the selected boxes are selected with the corresponding score

Comment: you are using AnnouncedPuResults to load the form which is extending activerecord, and not you/base/model, as far as it looks like , you should add the relevant action and view code